# How to explore external package in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using the Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers, and I am trying to browse the outline of external code such as HttpServlet. I do not need to see the code itself, but just the public functions and properties. It was very easy in Visual Studio by pressing F12 (or opening the object browser directly).

In Eclipse I am trying to achieve this by pressing F3, but it just displays a message to me stating "class not found".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this other answer to see if it answers your question:

[From within the Eclipse IDE, how can I show a list of types that exist in a jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870424/from-within-the-eclipse-ide-how-can-i-show-a-list-of-types-that-exist-in-a-jar)

It seems like you're looking for Visual Studio's "object browser" functionality within Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You need the JDK installed, so that you can view java source code

Comment: It is installed for me

Comment: Is your eclipse is configure to use it ? Check in preference / java / compiler